# Including webfont on Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, fonts, google-fonts

I want to use a font y Google. I used it on a static website and it is OK. But when I use it on Laravel, it doesn't work.

I did exactly the same as static website an it works.

I do not understand, which part of code can I give you for having help ?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share the relevant code so we can see what might be wrong

Comment: css : http://pastebin.fr/82471 ; php/html : http://pastebin.fr/82472

Comment: There are some styles that use roboto in that code but there are no elements that have the associated styles. I'm assuming you do have those elements in parts of the code you haven't shared and those are the ones that don't appear correct?

Comment: here is a view : http://pastebin.fr/82602 and here is the layout including stylsheets : http://pastebin.fr/82603 and here is a part of home.css included ins master.blade.php  http://pastebin.fr/82604:

Comment: You have used the font "Roboto" on some tags in your stylesheet. But, then I saw your blade template and couldn't not find any of those tags.

Comment: as you can see I use <p class="txt"> who has a "roboto" class in home.css

Comment: I checked your settings on laravel project and all seem to be in order. Have you double checked that the CSS file is being loaded?

Comment: Yes it is loaded, I verified it by watching source code and click home.css and it is loaded